# How to change file after merge?

Tags: git, package.json

When I develop the feature I can use custom branch of the repo in the package.json.

```
"my-awesome-repo": "git@github.com:my-awesome-repo.git#feature/1",
```

And I commit this change. Then I merge this code to master and I should change custom branch *feature/1* to *master* for production build.

I want to automate this for every merge to master. How can I do it?

Comment: You want automation of merging commits from your branch to master..... why are you using a branch then? Why not commit directly to master?

Comment: Why do you need the file *in* the branch to reflect which branch it is in? What is the end result here?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen
I have a lot of dependencies in the project and this is the way to develop the features, using the specific branch. F.e. when I develop feature/1 I use this branch in whole repos that have changes. After merge to master whole branches in every repo I can build to production from master. But first of all I should change the dependency in package.json.

Comment: "build to production", it seems you have a build system in place, shouldn't this build system be able to pick up the branch name you're currently building from, without it being explicitly stated in the files themselves?

Comment: In any case, you *might* be able to jerryrig something with post-merge hook, otherwise you're going to have to look for 3rd party solutions to this automation. The reason I'm asking about what you're using this value for is precisely because this is not easily done, if at all possible, with just git, and is usually handled by the CI system, which already knows the branch name it is currently building.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen thanks. I have to review my git flow.